# Show specific data based on a parameter django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hi everyone I have a question, I want to show the information for an specific pokemon when I type its name on the url (ex: http:/0.0.0.0:8000/pokemon/Pikachu) I can display all the information in the model but not the one that belongs to that specific name, how can I do it?

Here's my view

```
class PokemonView(APIView):
    """Pokemon API View"""

    def get(self, request):
        """Returns the pokemon information"""
        pokemon_info = Pokemon.objects.all()
        serializer = PokemonSerializer(pokemon_info, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

> And this one is my serializer

```
class PokemonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Transform the pokemon data (model) into a json"""
    class Meta:
        model = Pokemon
        fields = '__all__'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using a get parameter?

**URL:**
`http:/0.0.0.0/8000/pokemon/?name=Pikachu`

You would then access the name like so:

```py
class PokemonView(APIView):
    """Pokemon API View"""

    def get(self, request):
        """Returns the pokemon information"""

        # try to get the name:
        name = request.GET.get('name')

        # search for pokemon by name:
        if name:
            pokemon = Pokemon.objects.get(name=name)
            
            # return pokemon:
            ...

        # do something else:
        else:
            ...
```